# Will Hotspot Shield hide multiple "votes" from the same computer?

Tags: hotspot

There is a website that allows One Vote Per Computer, per day.  Does Hotspot Shield hide the ip, isp and other personal identifying information?  For example, if someone voted their "one vote" for the day, then RESET hotspot shield, would the website hosting the vote be able to see that multiple votes came from the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

Since Hotspot Shield establishes a secure connection to their gateway and then goes out through their gateway, once you vote, that IP may be registered.  Once you connect in again and go out through the same gateway, the same IP may be detected again and be blocked.  The site may not see your IP, but they will see Hotspot Shield's IP.